# Very minor edits, e.g. punctuation

Tags: support, editing, retagging

Is there going to be a way for me to make a very minor edit, e.g. punctuation, without pushing the question to the top of the activity date sort?

Answer (score 8):

[No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers/26496#26496).