# Is there a way to make minor edits on old answers w/o bringing them to top of stack?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing, retagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very minor edits, e.g. punctuation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/very-minor-edits-e-g-punctuation)

I noticed a sign error in an old answer of mine. I wanted to fix it, but I don't really want to bring this old question to the top of the stack when there's fundamentally nothing new to read there. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/47/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yeah, it's an exact duplicate, thanks. I didn't see that question. I disagree with the official policy, but it's not a huge deal.

Comment: Just go ahead and make the edit. (A sign error isn't a minor edit in the sense of the other question, even though the answer to the underlying question is the same)